# React Tcomb form can't get the value of DateInput from factory

Tags: reactjs, tcomb

I have problem with tcomb-form. 
Inside my tcomb-form I declared an factory that have the an DateInput (@blueprintjs/datetime) Component.

But when I get the values of the form. The that input field is undefined. Look like tcomb-form can't get the values from my DateInput component.

Here is code.

```
this.state = {
  currentDate: new Date()
};


const Type = t.struct({
  invoiceDate: t.maybe(t.String),
});

const formOption = {
  fields: {
    invoiceDate: {
      factory: l => 
      this.DateInputField({ ...l, getBundleById, currentDate }),
      attrs: {
        className: 'pt-input',
      },
      error: 'error text'
    }
  }
};

handleDateInputChange = (date, locals) => {
this.setState({
  currentDate: date
}, () => {
  console.log('this.state.currentDate: ', this.state.currentDate);
  locals.onChange(this.state.currentDate);
});
```

};

```
DateInputField = (locals) => {
// console.log('locals: ', locals);
return (<div>
  <label className="pt-label garage-info__label" htmlFor="invoiceDate">Invoice Date: </label>
  <DateInput value={locals.currentDate} onChange={date => this.handleDateInputChange(date, locals)} />
</div>);
```

};

```
My form: 
<form className="col-xs-12" onSubmit={onUploadInvoice}>
          {
            !isSuccess &&
            <TcombContainer
              type={Type}
              values={{
                invoiceDate: currentDate
              }}
              options={formOption}
              onChange={onChangeUploadInvoice}
            />
          }

          {
            isError &&
            <div className="pt-callout pt-intent-danger">
              { isError.message }
            </div>
          }

          {
            isRequest &&
            <div className="pt-callout pt-intent-warning">
              <span>{ getBundleById('CARENET.ASSIGNMENT.EDIT.UPLOAD.REQUEST') }</span>
            </div>
          }

          {
            (!isRequest && !isSuccess) &&
            <div className="text-center">
              <button type="submit" className="pt-button pt-large pt-intent-success">
                {getBundleById('CARENET.ASSIGNMENT.EDIT.FORM.TYRES.SUBMIT_BUTTON')}
              </button>
            </div>
          }
        </form>
```